# Database design help

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a SQL database that stores vouchers and everytime a voucher is issued, I want to store the quantity, should I have 2 separate tables, 1 for vouchers and 1 for voucherIssued or I can just add a issuedQuantity column to my voucher table? Appreciate any advice given. Thanks.

Comment: If you want a good answer you're going to have to give more information than you've given. Is there additional information relevant to issued vouchers (such as to who or when)? If a voucher can be issued more than once (which it sounds like they can since you're asking about a quantity) then can they be issued at different times? To different people?

Comment: I agree that more information is required. For example, if your enterprise issues vouchers and this database is to be the trusted source of data relating to them then the requirements will be different. For example, for each you may need to record a unique voucher number, value, expiry date, whether redeemed, etc (it may be possible to chunk data for some vouchers). Without these you risk falling foul of fraudsters and auditors!

Answer (score 1):

What else are you storing?  What is the voucher?  a piece of text, a filename, or something else?

it sounds like storing the voucher, and a count of how many times this voucher was issued is fine for now.  You may want to eventually record information about each time a voucher is issued, and then you probably don't need to store a specific count, just a row of information per voucher issued.

There really isn't enough information to give a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need an issuedQuantity column.

Separate tables are for one-to-many relationships like PurchaseOrder to PurchaseOrderItems.

You may think issuedQuantity is a 'many' but it is a single number so you have a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: While it true that one-to-one tables are not typical there's nothing categorically wrong about that [Cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling))

Comment: One-to-one tables do have a down side.  They add complexity and have slower performance (joins are slow).  An example of them being required might be some information about a record needing higher security (like SSN, salary, security clearance).

Answer (score -1):

It depends,

If you need to capture other data about each issue(when,who,where) then you will need another table to record the details of each issue.

You will still need an "issuedQty" column in the parent table to track the total number issued  whatever happens.

Comment: If issued vouchers are being stored in a separate table then one almost certainly **does not** want (and certainly doesn't need) to track the quantity of issued vouchers in the other table as well.

Comment: @Tom -- if you are capturing data about each individual issue you don't want to "sum()" the quantities from this table every time you require the total.

Comment: Actually, yes. That's exactly what you want to do in most cases. Denormalizing without a concrete and tested reason is overoptimization which is usually going to cause headaches down the road.

Comment: @Tom H.: Joe Celko: "You are not supposed to put a calculated column in a table in a pure SQL database ...too bad the real world is not as nice as the theoretical world. There are many types of calculated columns.... The third type of calculated data uses data in the same table, but not always in the same row in which it will appear. The fourth type uses data in the same database. These last two types are used when the cost of the calculation is higher than the cost of a simple read. In particular, data warehouses love to have this type of data in them to save time."

Comment: I don't disagree that there are times when you should denormalize a database for performance. I disagree with the notion that you "need" to do it in all cases and in my experience, for most databases it is not necessary and should be avoided. Also, this database design does not sound like a data warehouse to me. Maybe I'm mistaken, but I doubt it.